how make nohup log command it self
I use nohup like:
nohup ./cmd.sh --para=abc > ${PWD}/cmd_$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S").log 2>&1 &

How can I make the output log file include the command itself, i.e. the ./cmd.sh --para=abc > ${PWD}/cmd_$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S").log part could be found in the log file (say cmd_20241030_1315_00.log).
And any of the followings would be ok:
nohup ./cmd.sh --para=abc > ${PWD}/cmd_$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S").log 2>&1 &

nohup ./cmd.sh --para=abc > /real/path/cmd_20241030_1315_00.log

./cmd.sh --para=abc > /real/path/cmd_20241030_1315_00.log

./cmd.sh --para=abc


This question is similar to: Show command executed along with output in log file. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Put the command in a script with set -x and run the script with nohup
